# netty-tcnative issue after upgrading to netty 4.1.74

Tags: netty

we are using netty via vertx. all netty dependencies are brought by vertx, except

`io.netty:netty-tcnative:2.0.46.linux:x86_64`

which is a part of our build.
once we moved to a newer version of vertx, we got netty 4.1.74 instead of 4.1.72 and started to run into the issue below. it's not clear to me if it's related to https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/12101 or we are doing something wrong.

running java11 with SUSE.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_suse, netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64, netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_fedora, netty_tcnative_x86_64, netty_tcnative]
                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:114)
                                                              at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:705)
                                                              at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:146)
                                                              at io.vertx.core.net.impl.SSLHelper.resolveEngineOptions(SSLHelper.java:74)
                                                              ... 77 more
                                                              Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_suse
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:224)
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:105)
                                                                      ... 80 more
                                                              Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_suse.so
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:171)
                                                                      ... 81 more
                                                                      Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_suse in java.library.path: [/usr/local/lib]
                                                                              at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670)
                                                                              at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
                                                                              at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
                                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:376)
                                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:146)
                                                                              ... 81 more
                                                                              Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_suse in java.library.path: [/usr/local/lib]
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                                                                      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                                                                                      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:410)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:402)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:368)
                                                                                      ... 82 more
                                                              Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL
                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2627)
                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)
                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1837)
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:36)
at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:376)
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:203)
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:105)
                                                                      ... 80 more
                                                              Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_fedora
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:224)
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:105)
                                                                      ... 80 more
                                                              Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_fedora.so
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:171)
                                                                      ... 81 more
                                                                      Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_fedora in java.library.path: [/usr/local/lib]
                                                                              at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670)
                                                                              at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
                                                                              at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
                                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:376)
                                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:146)
                                                                              ... 81 more
                                                                              Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative_linux_x86_64_fedora in java.library.path: [/usr/local/lib]
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                                                                      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                                                                                      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:410)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:402)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:368)
                                                                                      ... 82 more
                                                              Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative_x86_64
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:224)
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:105)
                                                                      ... 80 more
                                                              Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative_x86_64.so
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:171)
                                                                      ... 81 more
                                                                      Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative_x86_64 in java.library.path: [/usr/local/lib]
                                                                              at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670)
                                                                              at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
                                                                              at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
                                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:376)
                                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:146)
                                                                              ... 81 more
                                                                              Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative_x86_64 in java.library.path: [/usr/local/lib]
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                                                                      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                                                                                      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                                                                                       at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:402)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:368)
                                                                                      ... 82 more
                                                              Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:224)
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:105)
                                                                      ... 80 more
                                                              Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative.so
                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:171)
                                                                      ... 81 more
                                                                      Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative in java.library.path: [/usr/local/lib]
                                                                              at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670)
                                                                              at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
                                                                              at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
                                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:376)
                                                                              at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:146)
                                                                              ... 81 more
                                                                              Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty_tcnative in java.library.path: [/usr/local/lib]
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                                                                      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                                                                                      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:410)
                                                                                      at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:402)
                                                                                      at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:368)
                                                                                      ... 82 more
```

Comment: Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: @ravat-tailor actually I wasn't aware that our security department taylors a custom version of tcnative-classes jar. since the jar version was changed i just needed them to create a new jar with corresponding version. since we work in the same company this might be the case for you too :)